# Sample Curriculum for levels of English users

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

Just curious, where can I find a sample TEFL curriculum for different levels of English users for the ff:
Basic, Elementary, pre-intermediate, intermediate, upper intermediate and advance?

I'm really confused as to why there are lectures about present tenses in the Elementary level, while some place this in the intermediate. I'm looking for some sorts of standard guideline where I could base my lesson plan on.

Comment: Could you explain what _ff_ means in your first sentence?

Comment: @Shoe Sorry, what I meant was following.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for pedagogical resources, not about the functional aspects of the English language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The levels you name are somewhat arbitrary, since there is no agreement on when, for example, a pre-intermediate student enters the intermediate level. And to my knowledge there is no standard guideline for determining the order of difficulty of the various grammatical elements in English. In any case, difficulty will vary according to the native language of the learner.

A further question is whether a TEFL syllabus should be based on the order of difficulty, even if this can be established reliably. Modern TEFL methodologies such as *Task-Based Learning* do not use  difficulty but usefulness as the basis for organising the syllabus.

If you want to see how a very popular ELT coursebook series organises its content, then have a look at *Headway* by *Oxford University Press*. This might give you some useful ideas. But, ultimately, you will need to decide for yourself how to organise your course, based on the needs of your learners.